# How to import data from excel to sql server database?

Tags: sql-server, import

I am trying to import data from excel to sql server database but the problem I am facing is since the id column in table is auto increment identity type I was trying to copy data from excel sheet that did not contain the id column as I thought that since id column is auto increment it would populate automatically. **But it is throwing error cannot insert null in column id**. Can anyone provide me with a solution?

Comment: Import *how*? With the wizard? Just *don't* include the ID column if you don't want to use its values

Comment: If this is a one time thing you can use the Import/Export wizard that's built in SSMS. just rightclick on the database, choose "task" and then "import data".

Comment: Not just a one-time thing. You can save the SSIS package generated by the wizard for reuse and modification (eg removing columns, adding transformations)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos- I am getting error cannot insert null in column id

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos-yes with wizard and destination is SQlserver native